# Webpack ignore chunking for production build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a Webpack configuration which is splitting my code in my project. What I am trying to do is to ignore the chunking and generate a single file if it is a production build.

This is my webpack configuration file:
https://gist.github.com/alyn000r/5663c1036ab8e60695ba4db4e866df5f

This is my index.js because of which chunking is happening:

```
if (typeof require.ensure !== `function`) require.ensure = (d, c) => c(require);  // mocha test runner polyfill

/**
 * require.ensure allows asynchronous chunk loading of the component, which means an extra HTTP hop to download the component,
 * in exchange of smaller initial download footprint.
 * - Use require.ensure for components that are least frequently used
 * - Use require.ensure for components that import libraries that are large in size
 */
export function lookup(componentName, callback) {
    switch (componentName) {
        // ============================== Components ===============================
        case 'dD':
            callback(require('./components/dD'));
            break;
        case 'eBL':
            callback(require('./components/eBL'));
            break;
        case 'essay':
            callback(require('./components/essay'));
            break;
        case 'hSM':
            require.ensure([], require => callback(require('./components/hSM')));
            break;
```

This is what its generating right now:

[image]

Please help me generate a single file if (isProduction) is true

I have tried removing the CommonChunks Plugin and MinChunkSizePlugin if isProduction but the chunks are still happening. I have also tried to remove

```
jsonpFunction: `jsonpFunction${jsonpPackageName}`,
    chunkFilename: `${packageName}/${packageName}-[id].js`,
```

But it still generates 0.0.js, 1.1.js, 2.2.js ....

Please tell me what am I missing. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can disable code splitting by limiting the max number of chunks to 1 with the [`LimitChunkCountPlugin`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#limitchunkcountplugin):

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1
    });
]
```

Comment: Hey, this generates two files cas-core-renderer.js and cas-core-renderer-0.js. I tried setting it to maxChunks: 0 but that I believe disables the plugin because it generated 5 files again. Thank you for your help though!